# Creating n threads, max 5 active at a time, wait for all to finish before continuing

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, selenium-webdriver, java-threads

I'm building a web crawler with Selenium and MVC design pattern in Java. I'm trying to achieve three things:

1. To create n number of threads depending on the length of my database (sidb) storing search settings.
2. Because I'm having a TablePanel in my GUI with the data, i need all threads to finish before proceeding. Otherwise i will lose some data because table.refresh() method is called to early.
3. As more than 5 Firefox windows running at once will slow down my computer too much i would like a maximum of 5 threads running at any given time.

The following code solves the first problem, and to some degree the second.  I had to make a nasty Thread.sleep() to prevent it from running refresh on the table too early.

```
public void runSearchItems() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sidb.getSize(); i++) {
            final int num = i;
            Thread tn = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getDomainBox().equalsIgnoreCase("www.someURL.com") == true) {
                        String searchField = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getSearchField();
                        int searchCat = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getSearchCategory();
                        boolean defect = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().isDefectCheck();
                        boolean region = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().isRegionCheck();
                        String arrange = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getArrangeBy();
                        ArrayList<SiteData> ls = wb.searchWebSite(searchField, searchCat, defect, region, arrange);
                        for (int j = 0; j < ls.size(); j++) {
                            db.addSiteData(ls.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            tn.start();
            try {
                tn.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you should look at a Thread Pool.

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to your code

```
public void runSearchItems() { 
    List<Thread> allThreads = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < sidb.getSize(); i++) {
            final int num = i;
            Thread tn = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override 
                public void run() { 
                    if (sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getDomainBox().equalsIgnoreCase("www.someURL.com") == true) {
                        String searchField = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getSearchField();
                        int searchCat = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getSearchCategory();
                        boolean defect = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().isDefectCheck();
                        boolean region = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().isRegionCheck();
                        String arrange = sidb.getSearhItem().get(num).getFormevent().getArrangeBy();
                        ArrayList<SiteData> ls = wb.searchWebSite(searchField, searchCat, defect, region, arrange);
                        for (int j = 0; j < ls.size(); j++) {
                            db.addSiteData(ls.get(j));
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 


            allThreads.add(tn);
        } 



        for(Thread t:allThreads)
            t.start();


        for(Thread t:allThreads)
            try { 
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
```

But yes, you are better of with Thread Pool

as an example https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/

Comment: there may be some syntax error(wrote it from memory). do comment if you find some.

Comment: tried to run 8 threads.... all seem to be running... tested using the code https://pastebin.com/s1mzuagq

Comment: I figured it out, and got thread pool implemented, thank you!